# marginal cdf and cdf of marginals

Tags: mathematical-statistics, joint-distribution, definition, marginal-distribution

given a joint distribution of 2 variables $P(X,Y)$, is the cdf of the Y-marginal distribution equals to the Y-marginal of the cdf of $P(X,Y)$?

Comment: It depends on how these terms are defined: what holds is that $$F_Y(y)=\mathbb P(Y<y)=\mathbb P(X<\infty,Y<y)=F_{X,Y}(\infty,y)$$

Comment: What is the Y-marginal of the cdf of P(,Y)?